# Java naming convention for classes present outside of service and inside the service

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Lets say I have some REST service.
This service has method:
`public void match(A request)`

We need to take class `A`, convert it to some class `B` that represent this request that we got (maybe with some less, more, slightly processed fields), work with this class `B` inside the service and return some response.

Is there a naming convention for classes `A`, `B`? If not, what do you guys use?

I dont have code samples since its a theoretical question.
I dont think the domain really matters, Im not asking about an exact name, something like A=ServiceRequest and B=Request are also fine, obviously the domain should be in the name too but thats not the question here, im asking about how to differentiate them.

Comment: Depends on your domain I would say.

Comment: Please, be a little more precise. Put some more code in here to show what your described workflow really looks like.

Comment: Naming conventions are not as much as about what exact name you give your class (which depends on the build/function of the class) as it is about how you differentiate between variables/classes/constants/...

Comment: Edited the question, hopefully its clearer now

Comment: "how to differentiate them", don't create two classes to perform a single task. also: good use of packages

Comment: Its not the same task, its an outer and inner model, I receive the request in a certain way but I might want to transform it into something else to work with without having to change the request class which is a published API